# Detect other apps with access to NFC module in android

Tags: android, nfc

Is there a way to detect programmatically other applications that are installed in an android device and have access to device's NFC module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all installed packages (PackageInfo) on the device, and from there you can look up for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

by using [PackageInfo.requestedPermissionsFlags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissionsFlags)

Comment: I will mark this correct, Thank you for pointing the direction. Indeed I used the getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages and crawled in packageInfo.requestedPermissions for "android.permission.NFC".